# How to realize observer pattern with CDI Events?

Tags: java, events, cdi, observer-pattern

In my system I have 2 scenarios:

1. Component X produces events which are observed by Y.
2. Component X produces events which should be observed by component F. F decides if event should be ignored or modified and passes it to Y.

Is it possible to implement it with CDI events?

Answer (score 1):

CDI only providers capabilities for broadcast style/topic events.  There is no event filtering in CDI.

The only way I can think to do the equivalent is to come up with a qualifier.  Perhaps `F` can `@Observes @A @B SomeObject` whereas `Y` can `@Observes @C @B SomeObject`.  When `F` gets an event, it can refire it using `@C @B` as the qualifiers.

Comment: It is good solution, but it works when we realize only one scenario. I would like to implement both and enable one with configuration.

Comment: Configuration is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create some sort of proxy between event producers and event consumers:

```
class EventProducer{
    @Inject private Event<EventObject> event;

    public void produce(){
        event.fire(new EventObject());
    }
}
```

Proxy:

```
class EventsProxy{

    @Inject private Event<EventObjectForY> event_1;
    @Inject private Event<EventObjectForF> event_2;

    void observe(@Observes EventObject){
        if(eventObjectEligibleForF()){
            EventObjectForF f = copyEventObjectToEventObjectForF();
            event_2.fire(f);
        }
        EventObjectForY y = copyEventObjectToEventObjectForY();
        event_2.fire(y);
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
class EventConsumer{
    public consume(@Observes EventObjectForY obj){
    }
}
```

But please remember that this is just pseudo-code.